# Codility nested algorithm test performance

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm attempting the Codility 'Nested' test in Javascript.

The test is as below:

```
A string S consisting of N characters is called properly nested if:

S is empty;
S has the form "(U)" where U is a properly nested string;
S has the form "VW" where V and W are properly nested strings.
For example, string "(()(())())" is properly nested but string "())" isn't.

Write a function:

function solution(S);

that, given a string S consisting of N characters, returns 1 if string S is properly nested and 0 otherwise.

For example, given S = "(()(())())", the function should return 1 and given S = "())", the function should return 0, as explained above.

Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:

N is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000];
string S consists only of the characters "(" and/or ")".
```

My solution is the following:

```
function solution(S) {
    const elements = S.split('')
    const stack = []
    if (elements.length > 1000000) return 0
    if (elements[0] == ')') return 0
    if (elements[0] == '(') stack.push('(')
    for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
        const currentElement = elements[i]
        if (currentElement !== '(' && currentElement !== ')') return 0
        if (i>0){
            if (stack[stack.length-1] == '(' && currentElement == ')') stack.pop()
            else stack.push(currentElement)
        }
    }
        if (stack.length) return 0
        else return 1
}
```

This is correct but returns only 75% on performance, i can't see how to further improve the efficiency, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: All you need is a counter. Increment the counter when you see a `(`, decrement it when you see a `)`. If the counter is ever negative, or if the counter is not zero at the end, then return 0.

Comment: So it’s the array push and pop operations themselves that are reducing efficiency?

Comment: The `push` and `pop` operations definitely reduce efficiency.

Comment: Can anyone write a working solution? I don't see how you can use counters to preserve the order of the array. If for example you end up with ())()(()() this would look correct with a single counter as the open and closed brackets would cancel out but they were actually contextually incorrect

Comment: `())` counter: 1,0,-1. *"If the counter is ever negative, [...], then return 0."*

Comment: [https://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-nesting-by-codility](https://codesays.com/2014/solution-to-nesting-by-codility/) ?

Comment: So you can accept answers... what's wrong with mine?

Answer (score 3):

I think you are doing this way too complicated. Split isn't necessairy. Also the problem statement says the string only contains `(` and `)`. So the solution can be as simple as this (passes all tests):

```
function solution(S) {
    let count = 0
    for (const c of S) {
        if (c == '(')
            count++
        else if (--count < 0)
            return 0
    }
    return count == 0 ? 1 : 0
}
```

Btw. this statement in your code is wrong:

```
if (currentElement == ')' && openCount > 0)  openCount = openCount - 1
else openCount = openCount + 1
```

If the count would become negative because there are too many `)` you will increase the counter. So maybe it isn't a performance problem after all. Same for the solution with the stack: if the stack is empty you look for stack[-1] and this is undefined so you push the next element (although there it doesn't fail because you will push `)` and this will never be consumed). Also it would make more sense to push the index of the opening braces on the stack so that you could (if you wanted to) show the pairings of the braces, which `(` belongs to which `)`. If you just push `(` on the stack you can as well use a counter.

Answer (score 0):

Following suggestions in the comments, i tried using a counter.

This still fails on efficiency though, being penalised on broad tree with deep paths.

```
function solution(S) {
    // write your code in JavaScript (Node.js 8.9.4)
    const elements = S.split('')
    let openCount = 0
    if (elements.length > 1000000) return 0
    if (elements[0] == ')') return 0
    if (elements[0] == '(') openCount = 1
    for (i=0; i < elements.length; i++){
        const currentElement = elements[i]
        if (currentElement !== '(' && currentElement !== ')') return 0
        if (i>0){
            if (currentElement == ')' && openCount > 0)  openCount = openCount - 1
            else openCount = openCount + 1
        }
    }
        if (openCount !== 0) return 0
        else return 1
}
```

Comment: Here an example of an expression that your code would say it is ok: `()))`, you can see why in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many "if"s in your solution. Try to understand maraca's answer. Or, check my solution below (99% same)

```
function solution(S) {
    let stack = 0;
    for (let i=0; i<S.length; i++) {
        S[i] === '(' ? stack++ : stack--; 
    
        if (S[i] === '(') {
            stack++
        } else {
            stack--;
            if (stack < 0) return 0;
        }
    }
    return stack === 0 ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function solution(S) {
  let stack=[];
  if(!S){
   return 1;
  }
 for(let i=0;i<S.length;i++){
    if(S[i]==='('){
     stack.push(S[i]);
   }else if(stack.length){
     stack.pop();
    }else{
    return 0;
  }
 }
return stack.length ? 0: 1;
}
```

Comment: This soution gave me 100% score on codility with O(n) complexity.

Comment: explaining how it differs from OP's solution would be nice for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

100% on Codility

```
const nesting = (s) => {
if (!s.length) {
    return 1;
}

if (s.indexOf('(') === -1 && s.indexOf(')') === -1) {
    return 1;
}

const arr = [];
const map = {
    '(': ')'
};

for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    if (s[i] === '(' || s[i] === ')') {
        if (!arr.length || map[arr[arr.length - 1]] !== s[i]) {
            arr.push(s[i]);
            continue;
        }

        if (map[arr[arr.length - 1]] === s[i]) arr.pop();
    }
}

return arr.length > 0 ? 0 : 1;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please don't post code-only answers.  Please [edit] to add some context and explanations.